# Is it safe to run a ThreadPoolExecutor inside another ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I have a situation in which I want to divide an I/O bound task based on some parameters. In that task, I want to do further division based on some other calculated parameters. Let me try to illustrate the scenario via some basic code:

```
def inner_task(a, b, c, d):
    some_result = doWork(a, b, c, d)
    return some_result

def outer_task(a, b):
   c, d = SomeCalculations()
   with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as inner_pool:
       inner_pool.submit(inner_task, a, b, c, d)
      
if __name__ == '__main__':
   with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as outer_pool:
       outer_pool.submit(outer_task, a, b)
```

My question is that, whether it is safe to do something like that (basically a thread pool inside another pool) both from a safety and performance point of view?.

P.S. I know that I can simply create one pool with 10 x 4 workers and assign jobs to them without dividing them into two tasks but, in this way my implementation is encapsulated much better and everything stays nicely in its own place.

Thanks for your time to review my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Threads don't technically run inside another thread. There is no parent-child relationship between threads. They all run in parallel inside a process no matter from which threads they are created. It is therefore perfectly safe to run a `ThreadPoolExecutor` inside a task run by another `ThreadPoolExecutor` and let the abstraction manage the logical relationships for you.

The only downside to nesting small pools inside a parent pool compared to creating one large pool would be that pools with heavier-loading tasks would then not be able to take advantage of available threads in pools with lighter duties, potentially costing some overall performance.